# Strain Energy Problem

Tags: materials

A bar of length L and of uniform cross-section area A and second moment of area 1 is subjected to pull P.If  the young's modulus of elasticity of the bar material is E,the expression for **strain energy** stored in the bar will be
1)P2L2/2AE  2)PL2/2EI
3)PL2/AE    4)P2L/AE

**(Note:The  P2L2 and 2AE in the option is P squared,L squared and 2 times AE respectively)**

Answer (score 1):

5) None of the above.

The strain energy stored in the bar will be $$U = \frac{1}{2}P\Delta$$

where $$\Delta = \frac{PL}{AE}$$

or
$$U=\frac{P^2L}{2AE}$$

See [Strain Energy](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_I/BookSM_Part_I/08_Energy/08_Energy_02_Elastic_Strain_Energy.pdf)